# How to attach scroll event on FancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a big fancybox popup and contains scroll, And I need any event to attach scroll on this fancybox popup.

I'm already try some events like:

```
$('.fancybox-inner').off("scroll").on("scroll", function(){debugger;});
```

OR

```
$('#FancyBox').off("scroll").on("scroll", function(){debugger;});
```

and other ways, but nothing work.

is there anyone have a idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fancybox content is dynamically generated. As such you'll need to use a delegated event handler for the scroll event:

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.fancybox-inner', function() { 
  debugger;
});
```

Alternatively you could manually add the `scroll` event when the FancyBox is displayed using the built in events it exposes:

```
$('#yourFancyBox').fancybox({
  afterShow: function() {
    $('.fancybox-inner').on('scroll', function() {
      debugger;
    });
  }
  // other settings...
});
```

You can read more on the events available within the Fancybox library by reading their [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#event)